# SD file system possible in Ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem, format, sd-card

I plan on transferring Nintendo 3DS data to a larger SD card. For this Nintendo recommends formatting any SD card to the compliant SD file system created by the [SD Association](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/). Windows and Mac are of course options here. Is it possible to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried just formatting as `fat32`? It's the necessary format and, regardless of what Nintendo might say, most OSs format them just fine.

Comment: @Kurankat, that is certainly worth a try. I wanted to ask anyway, as in the past I've been able to "move mountains" with nothing more than a one-liner in a terminal.